# Cannot connect to SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, authentication

tearing my hair out to be honest at this stage.

I have an installation of SQL Server 2008 express on my laptop. I've been trying to login to SQL Server Management Studio without success. I even did a fresh install yesterday and still no joy. On installation I selected to install the default instance with windows authentication, I have enabled remote connection in configuration manager.

The error message I get when I log in is as following:

> A network related or instance specific
>   error occured while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 25 - connection
>   string is not valid)(Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error:87)

I've tried googling it and all I can see is help for people who get error 26 (which I was getting before I did the fresh install.

The settings for login are:

Server Type: Database Engine
Server Name: TARAW-PC\MSSQLSERVER
Authentication: Windows Authentication

Comment: Have you installed SQL Server 2008 **Express** (along with VS2010 or something)? In that case, your instance would be named "SQLEXPRESS", so you'd have to connect to `TARAW-PC\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: Hi, I did install it with VS2010, however it didn't seem to be logging in for me then either so I did a fresh install of just SQL Server 2008 Express. I tried TARAW-PC\SQLEXPRESS, and TARAW-PC\MSSQLEXPRESS with no luck. If it makes any difference, when I used the above two names I got the error 26, however when I use the one I've posted, I get error 25.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you check if your sql services are running.

In your start -> Run, type `net start mssqlserver`

Then try the login

Comment: Hi Sachin, Tried this, still same error. SQL Server, SQL Server Browser are running, however SQL Server Agent isn't. Would this make a difference?

Comment: @TaraWalsh - That would not make difference. Can you check your servername. Can you try giving localhost or '.' for serverName when logging in to management studio

Comment: Sachin you beauty! localhost worked perfectly. Can't believe it. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to login to my local installation using loclahost, too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Try to give only your machine name.
Like if it is `Your machine name/serverInstance` so simply give it only `your machine name` then try to login.

---

Explanation why this trick works: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531.aspx) Microsoft writes

> An instance is either the default instance or a named instance. The default instance name is MSSQLSERVER. It does not require a client to specify the name of the instance to make a connection.

So if you created default instance (MSSQLSERVER) or named instance with name MSSQLSERVER you then should not add the instance name but just use the server's name (your machine name).

Comment: Why the h$&% did this work?!  I've set up dozens of instances and connected to other peoples' and it has *always* been `servername\instance`.

Comment: This worked. I have sql server 2012 express and 2014 developer side by side.

Comment: This worked for SQL Server 2019 and SSMS v18. Just localhost, no instance name. What a silly problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Azure SQL Server**, I would look at the following link: [Guidelines for Connecting to Azure SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/ee336282.aspx)
I would try one of the following first to see if these two aren't your main issues:

1. Specify the database you are connecting to. **Options > Connect To Database**. You will want to copy the name of the database here. This solved my issue.
2. If you are putting the port after the URL of the SQL server. Example: dbname.database.windows.net:1433 (which makes you get this error). If I didn't have the port after the URL, it threw a login error issue.

After doing both of those and making sure everything else in the link I provided you is right or completed, you should be able to connect.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and running `net start mssqlserver` also didn't work until i went to task manager > services and start the `SQLSERVERAGENT` service manually

Answer (score 0):

You will also see this error if you prefix the instance name with double blackslashes, eg. attempt to connect to \host\sqlserver instead of host\sqlserver - an easy mistake to make if you're used to typing UNC paths.

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is pretty old but I had the same issue today and fixed it by myself.
The issue was an IP setting in the Sql Server Configuration Manager
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldaGa.png)

I had an IPv4 in the IP-Addess field and changing it to an IPv6 made it work.