# Microsoft SQL Server , Error : 87

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am really tired, it's been 3 days that I can't open my SQL Server Management Studio. I got connection string error with number 87. Below screenshot show my problem:

[image: Picture number 1]

[image: Picture number 2]

And I use `localhost\MSSQLSERVER` with error 87 and `Arash-PC` (my machine name) with error number 2.

And I tried `sqlcmd -U sa -S Arash-PC` too

Comment: Are you sure your sql server instance is running?

Comment: Try on the command line prompt `telnet localhost 1433` - do you have a response (blank screen)?

Comment: Please check the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870966/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: If you mean in cmd window i got this error : 'telnet' is not recognized an internal or external command, operable program or batch file .

Comment: yes i run this code too : Run, type net start mssqlserver

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas : No , I dont know . How can i check it ?

Comment: @user841635 : please add telnet from control panel -> add-remove windows features

Comment: @Anton Kruglov Thank you . I run it twice . First time i don't get any message ( blank )  But second time i got an error : Connecting to localhost ... Could not open connection to the host , on port 1433 : Connect failed

Comment: @user841635 : that means you cannot connect to the SQL server port. It is either network issue (least probable as you are running locally), service is stopped or there is a security issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 21):

You need to check in your **SQL Server Configuration Manager** what services and instances you have installed. Go to `Start Menu > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server (version) > Configuration Tools` and launch the appropriate Configuration Manager. You should see a screen something like this:

[image]

Find the **SQL Server (.....)** service(s), and make sure the service is started.

If you find a `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` service started, then you have a **(unnamed) default instance** to which you can connect using

```
.
(local)
Arash-PC
```

You **MUST NOT** supply the `MSSQLSERVER` as the instance name!

If you find any other `SQL Server (instance name)` service started (e.g. `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` in my screenshot), then the instance name (`SQLEXPRESS`) needs to be **appended** to the server name to connect to that instance:

```
.\SQLEXPRESS
(local)\SQLEXPRESS
Arash-PC\SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: Thank you . Its the problem . But i can't vote you ( i am new ) . It's stopped and i can't start it . I got this error : "The request failed or the service did not responed in a timely fashion . Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details." I don't know where is the log file ( If you want it )

Comment: @user841635: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: NO . My problem is still there . I just find the main problem .

Comment: My SQL Server does not start by this error : "The request failed or the service did not responed in a timely fashion . Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details."

Comment: I need help friends . Now with your help my problem was found . Please solve it .

Comment: @user841635: and have you consulted the event log, and the applicable error logs for details?? What do they say??

Comment: Event 7024 : The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated with the following service-specific error: Cannot find object or property .

Comment: Event 7045 : A service was installed in the system. Service Name: SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER) Service File Name: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\ReportingServicesService.exe" Service Type: user mode service Service Start Type: auto start Service Account: NT Service\ReportServer

Comment: Event 7001 : The SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) service depends on the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service which failed to start because of the following error: The service has returned a service-specific error code.

Comment: Event 7045 : A service was installed in the system. Service Name: SQL Server Distributed Replay Client Service File Name: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\DReplayClient\DReplayClient.exe" Service Type: user mode service Service Start Type: demand start

Comment: You MUST NOT supply the MSSQLSERVER as the instance name! this was the mistake i was doing ..

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are not running out of space on the drive where SQL is installed. Try rebooting as well.
2. Verify that the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is started. Click Start, click Administrative Tools, click Services, and scroll to SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER). If it is not started, right-click the service, select Properties, in Startup Type select Automatic, click Apply, click Start, and then click OK. Make sure service started. If service did not start - you need to analyze event log. Alternatively - try reinstalling/repairing SQL server.
3. Make sure you have no network problems - try temporary disabling any firewalls(including Windows Firewall) and antiviruses.
4. If service is started and firewalls disabled but still no luck - time to check `SQL Server Configuration Manager` settings. In detail it is described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156468(v=sql.105).aspx). Shortly I would recommend first enable all protocols in both server **and client** sections. Reboot. Check it works. If that would not help - then try disabling everything apart from TCP/IP (both server and client sections). Reboot again.

If above does not help - try reinstalling SQL Server. Just make sure you have saved your databases 1st. To save them - stop sql server service, and copy your *.mdf and *.ldf (from SQL server Data folder) files to safe location. Later on you can attach them. If you are not sure where your SQL server Data folder located - just search for files with mdf extension.

**Edit:**
Successful telnet showing SQL server port is up looks this way:
[image: start telnet]
[image: connected successfully]

**Edit2:**

Launch **Event Viewer**:

[image: Launch Event Viewer]

Click **System**, then **Filter Current Log**:
[image: Click System, then Filter Current Log]

Setup **filter** as shown below:
[image: Setup filter]

Then look for **SQL**-related events:
[image]

Usually event text provides information why MSSQLSERVER service fails to start. If the text is unclear please google it for more details.

Comment: In Administrative Tools, SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) is not started,  Startup Type is Automatic but when i click on start , i got this error : "Windows could not start the sql server (MSSQLSERVER) on local Computer . For more information review thesystem event log ."  I was uninstall SQL Server twice ( one time with windows uninstaller and one time with Advanced Uninstaller PRO ) and reinstall it again . i really don't want reinstall my windows again .

Comment: My problem is still here. If you can help me .

Comment: Event 7024 : The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated with the following service-specific error: Cannot find object or property .

Comment: Event 7045 : A service was installed in the system.

Service Name:  SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
Service File Name:  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\ReportingServicesService.exe"
Service Type:  user mode service
Service Start Type:  auto start
Service Account:  NT Service\ReportServer

Comment: Event 7001 : The SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) service depends on the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service which failed to start because of the following error: 
The service has returned a service-specific error code.

Comment: Event 7045 : A service was installed in the system.

Service Name:  SQL Server Distributed Replay Client
Service File Name:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\DReplayClient\DReplayClient.exe"
Service Type:  user mode service
Service Start Type:  demand start

Comment: Microsoft online help : We didn’t find any information about this event in the TechNet Wiki or the Events and Errors Message Center.

Comment: Even if I have to reinstall Windows again, I am very grateful to you for your patience and your perfect answers .

Comment: Check and try changing account for SQL Service. Details [here](http://www.sqlserverblogforum.com/2011/11/sql-server-could-not-start-cannot-find-object-or-property-0x80092004/) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fef2424c-ac41-4f44-9f6c-9c6c426a38d0/cannot-start-mssqlserver-with-service-account?forum=sqldatabaseengine). Try `LOCAL SERVICE` first. Then try Administrator account.

Comment: Yes . its running now . but i got new error . Error 18456 . I've googled it . This is a widespread problem But the answers was not appropriate . The answers are appropriate for client-server . I think i should reinstall the windows . I hope it solve my problem .

Answer (score 0):

If your problem was the same as mine (or to anyone else whose attempting to connect to their MS SQL Server w/ a similar connection string), MSSQLSERVER is the default instance name when you set it up, if you don't provide an instance name. I omitted the MSSQLSERVER from the connection string and I was successfully able to connect.