# I just can't figure out what caused the error 87. mssql

Tags: sql-server

I need to access the other server database.
And I have to manipulate the settings, but I hit ERROR 87.
I've tried almost every attempt and even referred to StackoverFlow's content.
But it's not a solution. I really don't know why.

I also referred to this [Microsoft SQL Server , Error : 87](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085602/microsoft-sql-server-error-87)
But I've already tried.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XHels9Uo7T9HvZDYI7LfR4s6Md4GOaGP/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OEuANnMrUfTEyspEOkZfsPNYwYrgSWI2/view?usp=sharing

I don't know why it doesn't work. This error has cost me three days. 
We really need help.

I am using MSSQL 2008 R2. It's also Windows 10.

Comment: This can be a number of things, it could be a firewall issue, the sql server could not be setup to listen to TCP, the address is wrong, the server could not be running, etc...

Comment: Normally SQL Server uses TCP port 1433 (not 14033), unless of course you or whoever installed the server set it to use port 14033. *Besides that:* Stack Overflow allows uploading and embedding of images, which is much better than posting unexplained links to who-knows-what that might be gone tomorrow, next week or next year.

Comment: Well looking at the picture of what you are connecting to it appears that your IP address is incorrect.  You have 100.XX.1.xxx14033. You need a comma between IP address and port number, but I believe you have the wrong port.  Try 100.xx.1.xxx,1433.  Although you don't even need the 1433 as that is the default port.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution can help you

[image]

Comment: a few words of explanation would be required here. Answers that only have code/image are not considered good answers and are open for the downvoters